# Webscraping project: How to handle "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'"

Tags: web-scraping, attributeerror, nonetype

First time posting. I am learning python to do a web scraping project for my work. I am trying to collect information on the different projects this organisation shares on their website (my company has asked them permission, so that is all good).
I managed to run the code with no issues when scraping their HPV projects (52 in total), but when trying to scrape their HIV projects (a total of 131) I am running the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9556/1476973876.py in <module>
     11     project_description = soup.find('div', class_="column-1").text
     12     project_details = soup.find(class_="block-details")
---> 13     project_number = project_details.find("strong").text
     14     project_start = project_details.find("span", class_="bar-start").text
     15     project_end = project_details.find("span", class_="bar-end").text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

When scraping a list of just the first 10 URLs, it works fine.
I believe that the problem might be that one of the links **doesn't have the "strong" text**. If so, **how can I identify which link is not working**?

Here is my code (sorry if it is messy, would appreciate tips on how to improve)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time


st = time.time()
URLs = ['https://www.zonmw.nl/nl/onderzoek-resultaten/preventie/gezonde-wijk-en-omgeving/programmas/project-detail/preventieprogramma-4/hiv-self-testing-combined-with-internet-counselling-a-low-threshold-strategy-to-increase-diagnoses/', 'https://www.zonmw.nl/nl/onderzoek-resultaten/fundamenteel-onderzoek/programmas/project-detail/vici/training-b-cells-to-generate-broadly-neutralizing-hiv-antibodies/', 'https://www.zonmw.nl/nl/over-zonmw/e-health-en-ict-in-de-zorg/programmas/project-detail/diseasemanagement-chronische-ziekten/comorbidity-and-aging-with-hiv/', 'https://www.zonmw.nl/nl/onderzoek-resultaten/geneesmiddelen/programmas/project-detail/kennisbeleid-kwaliteit-curatieve-zorg/een-multidisiplinaire-richtlijn-voor-arbeidsgerelateerde-problematiek-bij-mensen-met-hiv/', 'https://www.zonmw.nl/nl/onderzoek-resultaten/doelmatigheidsonderzoek/programmas/project-detail/goed-gebruik-geneesmiddelen/study-to-optimize-antiretroviral-regimens-in-hiv-infected-women-who-want-to-breastfeed-panna-b/', 'https://www.zonmw.nl/nl/over-zonmw/e-health-en-ict-in-de-zorg/programmas/project-detail/active-and-assisted-living-aal2/u-topia-towards-empowering-older-persons-living-with-hiv/', ...]
data = []


for URL in URLs:
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    
    project_title = soup.find('h1').text
    project_description = soup.find('div', class_="column-1").text
    project_details = soup.find(class_="block-details")
    project_number = project_details.find("strong").text
    project_start = project_details.find("span", class_="bar-start").text
    project_end = project_details.find("span", class_="bar-end").text
    project_program = project_details.find("ul").text
    
    
    for node in project_details.find_all("p"):
        keywords = node.text.split(', ')
    project_recipient = keywords[-1]
    
    data.append((project_title, project_description, project_number, project_start, project_end, project_program, project_recipient))

et = time.time()

elapsed_time = et - st
print('Execution time:', elapsed_time, 'seconds')
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How can I identify which link is not working?**

1. Check the response's status code to see if the link is working or not -  `res.status_code == 200`
2. If links don't have the "strong" text, check if it has another class for that specific link and add it to your XPath.

**See the below sample for validation and improvement in code.**

First check if XPath/class is available or not then use .text. Also, initialize empty variables inside for loop so it won't throw an attribute error if an element is not found.

```
for URL in URLs:
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    
    # initialize the variables. It takes the default value blank if XPath is unavailable.
    project_number = project_start = ''
    
    # xpath - [Do not use .text directly on xpath]
    project_number_xp = project_details.find("strong")
    project_start_xp = project_details.find("span", class_="bar-start")
    
    # apply .text if XPath is available else it will throw an error.
    if project_number_xp:
        project_number = project_number_xp.text
    if project_start_xp:
        project_start = project_start_xp.text
        
    # Append the data
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

This is a much cleaner code and easier to follow through! 

I cherish this lesson and appreciate your time.

In the end, I approached it through brute force (had the will but lacked the knowledge hehe) and identified the URL that had a different structure. I will definitely apply what you've taught me in my code.

Cheers and have a great day!